# Submit web form in Android using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm currently working on an app for my school. For this I need to login to the school-homepage. I tried this with JavaScript. It fills in the username and the password in the form but it does not submit it. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
if(!send) {
view.loadUrl("javascript:{" +
"document.getElementById('username').value='" + username + "';" +
"document.getElementById('password').value = '" + password + "';" +
"var form = document.getElementsByName('submit');" +
"form[0].submit();};"
);
send = true;

}

}
});

wv.loadUrl("http://www.ggnauen.de");

}

});
```

And this is the html-code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text" value="">

<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text password" value="">

<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Anmelden">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just use this `form[0].click();};`

Comment: can you explain more details?

Answer (score -1):

Where have you mentioned the url to which the form is to be submitted?

Plus, is this a simple webview or a cordova project?

Comment: simple webview, the url is below.

Comment: It seems you are loading only the url http://www.ggnauen.de, without submitting any data to it.

Comment: Ah, I know what you mean. The website is loaded when the app starts. Then JS fills in the values and should submit the form. Then the site should reload. This is why I put the url down there.

Comment: Wie soll das gehen? Du musst die eingetragenen Daten ja an ein Formular senden welches die übermittelten Werte an den Server weiterleitet. Einfach nur die Daten an die URL zu hängen ist doch mehr als gefährlich und an dieser Stelle absolut unangebracht. Also: Daten mittels JS übermitteln und anschließend auf dem Server mit einer login.php auswerten. So würde ich vorgehen. In meinen Augen außerdem bedenklich jemanden für eine Schule etwas programmieren zu lassen, wenn derjenige hier Fragen stellt. Nichts gegen dich, aber ich finde, dass sollte jemand machen, der weiß wie das funktioniert.

Comment: @Sithys Sicherheit spielt hier so gut wie keine Rolle. Auf den Server komme ich auch nicht. Die App mache ich in meiner Freizeit, das ist auch alles mit der Schulleitung abgesprochen. Mach dir da mal keine Sorgen. Und warum hat es dann vorher auf diesem Wege geklappt, wenn du meinst, dass das nicht funktionieren kann? Ich will, dass username und password (eingegeben in eine edittext, gespeichert in einem string) in das Formular eingetragen werden, was ja auch super funktioniert, und dann praktisch der "Anmelden-Button" betätigt wird. Ich verstehe nicht, wo dein Problem liegt...

Comment: Ich verstehe noch gar nicht, warum das nicht geht. Hast du einen Link mit Testdaten zum einloggen? Oder mal den kompletten Code?

Comment: @Sithys mach dich aber nicht darüber lustig - es hat super funktioniert bis jetzt und das ist das was zählt :D
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyal7jr9a34vphs/MainActivity.java?dl=0

Comment: @Sithys hast du es gelesen?

Comment: Jo, aber erst morgen zeit mich drum zu kümmern.

Comment: @Sithys Super, danke!